# Most of my pages weren't indexed

Tags: google-search-console, google-index, xml-sitemap

I've submitted a sitemap (XML) of my Drupal (7) site to Google Webmaster Tools and it says that my sitemap contains 285 pages and that only 87 pages were indexed.

There are no errors and no additional info or problems. There are no duplicates.

Any idea why most of my pages weren't indexed?

When I Google my site ( i.e.: search the following in Google : `site:www.mysite.com/`), 
I get ~200 pages (results) which is better, but not perfect.

Comment: When did you submit the sitemap? It takes a few days/weeks before that number is correct.

Comment: See also: [The Sitemap Paradox](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/4803/the-sitemap-paradox)